# Como mockar dois vue componentes para realizar testes com cypress usando o mountVue()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

Estou tentando mockar dois componentes usando Cypress. Esses componentes foram criados em Vue. Para realizar testes unitários consegui mockar usando o `mountVue()` como vocês podem ver no exemplo abaixo:

```
import IButton from '../../../src/components/Button/Button.vue'
import mountVue from 'cypress-vue-unit-test'

describe('Button', () => {
  beforeEach(mountVue({
    template: `
      <IButton ref="button">Some Text</IButton>
    `,
    components: {
      IButton
    }
  }))

  it('displays the text inside it', () => {
    cy.contains('Some Text')
  })

  it('has "sumit" class and type by default', () => {
    cy.get('.i-button')
      .should('have.class', 'submit')
      .should('have.attr', 'type', 'submit')
  })
})
```

Então, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de mockar dois componentes ao mesmo tempo, usando o mesmo tipo de estrutura. A ideia é testar a integração de dois componentes.

Num arquivo separado, pensei começar importando os dois componentes (de produto e de seletor de quantidade) no mesmo arquivo:

```
import IProductCard from '../../../src/components/ProductCard/ProductCard.vue'
import IQuantitySelector from '../../../src/components/QuantitySelector/QuantitySelector.vue'
import mountVue from 'cypress-vue-unit-test'
```

e pensei em montar uma estrutura semelhante a isso:

```
 describe('With quantity selector', () => {
      beforeEach(mountVue(IQuantitySelector, IProductCard
      ))

      it('has produtc card and quantity selector', () =>
        cy.get('.i-quantity-selector')
          .should('exist')
          .should('be.visible')
      )
})
```

Porém quando executo o teste, ele monta primeiro um componente e depois o outro, mas eu queria que ele montasse os dois ao mesmo tempo. Não sei se existe a possibilidade de montar assim, mas eu já tentei de tudo. Já tentei criar uma *arrow function* `() => {}`, já tentei usar o `mount()` e o `shallowMount()` sem sucesso. Em todos os casos ele monta um, e monta o outro separado. Mas gostaria de montar os dois, e futuramente mais componentes juntos.

Comment: Geralmente quando quero testar a integração entre componentes eu carrego o html todo. A página carregada por completo (com todos os componentes). Gostaria de entender porque este requisito de testar 2 apenas? Carregar a página inteira (com todos os componentes carregados nela) não resolve?

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer testes entre alguns componentes, ates de testar a página completa. São componentes que fazem sentido de testar juntos, mas que não depende de toda uma página montada para testar!